# Are multiple sessions allowed in one computer using Google Colab?

Tags: google-colaboratory

Does Google Colab allow to run multiple session simultaneously?

1. Am I allowed to use multiple sessions if the GPU or CPU limit is not yet exceeded?
2. Is it possible to use multiple accounts with one computer?

Comment: Kindly mark the answer as accepted if it solved your problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 11):

Yes, you can run multiple colab instances of the same Google account.

Also, you can use different google accounts with different browsers and their incognito ones to run as many colabs as you want.

Sign in to chrome with one google id. Sign in to Chrome incognito with another Google id. Use a different browser for the 3rd and 4th id.

If you keep running your instances for 3+ days, GPU allocation to your account will be stopped for a day or two and then you will have it back.

Comment: If I create the colab-pro and use it with different sessions. how many instances I can use? if I make new session it allocate the new same GPU? even thoughj I create the multiple session with colab-pro I can not actually see how many resources im using

Comment: No you cant, I have pro subscription right now and it is not letting me run more than 1 notebook at a time with the same account

Comment: I'm able to use two sessions at once. However, I have to clone my notebook in order to do so.

Comment: Pro account holders can use 2 standard RAM instances and 1 High RAM instance simultaneously as of writing this comment.

Answer (score 0):

I can run 2 notebooks with the pro subscription + added GPU hours. That is, one with normal RAM and one with high ram seems to be the rule for it to work.